# Closed Question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38504/how-to-get-local-business-nationwide-exposure

I would like to know why such question was closed. I believe it is a very useful topic for future references. I'm asking about SEO practices to improve exposure of a local business website nationwide.

Now, if i could at least have an explanation why this is not useful, or doesn't fit this website, i would be very thankful.

It would help very much to receive some advice on how to improve, and that's why i asked that question. I can't understand why it was closed since it relates to SEO and good practices for webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is already covered in several other questions. See:

1. [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)
2. [How can I increase the traffic to my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/217/how-can-i-increase-the-traffic-to-my-site)
3. [traffic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic)
4. [advertising](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising)

Comment: My question is very specific, it's about a local website that ranks pretty well, specially because of local listings and mapa, rank better nationally. Most of those things on those topics i've done already.

Comment: @guisasso There's your problem. It's too specific. It must be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards You're wrong. And I fail to see how it would not be helpful to somebody else with the same doubt. Or maybe I should just assume that nobody has or will ever have a question similar to mine. Anyway, I was successful in my approach without an answer here.

Comment: Agree with @guisasso. There are millions of local businesses, trying to expand, that might benefit from info specific to their situation. If the rule is that every question needs to be helpful to every visitor, then exactly 0% of this site meets that criterion.