# Why was this closed and only by one person?

Tags: discussion, moderators, closed-questions, specific-question

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78289/getting-error-from-jpgraph-when-trying-to-export-to-pdf

I have a good answer for this that would potentially help a lot of people out.  But put on hold by one admin.  Just because YOU don't know doesn't mean someone else doesn't.  I really think this site needs better checks and balances.  I find that it is SUPER ANNOYING (yes all CAPS) that one person can put a question on hold with no intervention without even making a comment.  Really makes me want to use another SE site that has better mod reactions... long time user here rather annoyed.

Comment: This question was put on hold because it's in regards to _troubleshooting_, not because I didn't "know". As per our [Help Center's](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help) section about this under [What topics can I ask about here?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): `For example, we would close questions such as "What am I doing wrong here?" `. Questions of this type are often placed on hold for that reason, not to be annoying. If you had asked (politely) though, I would have suggested to edit it to be more applicable to others in the future so it might be reopened.

Comment: I might add that simple patience goes a long way. Your asking a question here about your question could have gone a long way toward your goal. But taking the tact that you have, do you really expect kind considerations? You will need to adjust how you handle *life* if you want to succeed. Otherwise, people will not be willing to help you advance.

Comment: @closetnoc - this is not Dan's site.  If it were Dan's site I would expect the exact thing.  The fact is look below and see that Dan had time to research my username (ooops sorry Dan, I was a mod with a different username) but he did not have time to reword my question so it met Dan's standards.  Who knows what Dan's standards are?  Nobody because Dan doesn't need to leave a comment when he doesn't like a question.

Comment: You will find that @dan is the fairest and the best moderator of this site along with bybe, John Conde, and Stephen Ostermiller. I stand by all of them! But in particular, dan because he is the one in particular that goes out of his way to help the OPs on this site and is extraordinarily generous with his time. If you have a problem with dan, then you have a problem. It is just that simple. It is not good that you are picking a fight with such a kind and considerate man. It is time for a re-evaluation of your stance.

Comment: @blankip It's not about whether I "like" a question, or don't "know" the answer as you previously claimed, but whether it fits within the guidelines of the site. Once again, there was a close reason provided as to why it didn't fit. If a question is off-topic, then it's up to the OP to edit it, which adds it back into the review queue. As one of the top editors on the site (and most thorough), if asked I'll certainly try to help, but you decided to make less than [civil](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), inaccurate accusations instead.

Comment: Let us know which site, year, and username you were a moderator under. I doubt any previous Stack Exchange moderator would behave in such a way, refer to moderators as "admins", or be so unaware of the standards and practices of Stack Exchange sites (unless removed).

Answer (score 3):

This was closed by one of the four moderators here.  Moderators can close questions on their own.

It wasn't closed because it can't be answered.   It was closed as off-topic because it's a troubleshooting question specific to one website and is not likely to help any future visitors.

You are more than welcome to edit this question to improve it.   Changing the subject to "What is JpGraph error: 25107" would be a good start.   Other people that encounter that error would benefit from an explanation of what it means.

Comment: I expect if I don't ask a question to someone's liking that they change the question so it meets their guidelines or the site's.  The fact is one person just closed it down without a comment (put on hold is effectively the same thing when you have one mod do this).   That is BS and not what stack is about.  I modded SE back in the day and this would never fly.   And the question isn't about troubleshooting it is about possible reasons for an error message.  This question is about why a mod would close a question instead of editing it.

Comment: @blankip It's up to the OP to edit the question to meet the guidelines, not the users or moderators that vote on it, as that might [change the meaning of questions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), which is not permissible. There was indeed a close reason supplied, stating: `Questions that are specific to one website are discouraged because they are unlikely to help future visitors. Examples include individual website reviews for SEO purposes and general website troubleshooting. See the How to Ask page for help improving this question.`

Comment: What was the SE site you "modded" and the year elected? I couldn't find any of your usernames in the election results of sites you're active on. SE moderators are certainly aware that moderator votes are [binding](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) and that they're expected to close questions [when they see a post they think should be closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124097/as-a-mod-when-should-i-vote-to-close-content-that-is-not-flagged). They're also aware that each site has its own specific criteria for deciding which questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: Lastly, moderators are keenly aware that [inappropriate language and rudeness](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) is prohibited on SE, and that every Stack Exchange site [states](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators): `If you have questions about the reasoning behind a moderator's actions, bring them up for discussion on meta. Remember to be constructive and polite.`

Comment: @dan -  As a new user to this stack I appreciate that you have taken the time to look at the history of my username but not have enough time to 1. add a comment before closing.  2.  Reword my question to your liking.   And again if you thought the question was about troubleshooting then you don't understand it.

Comment: @blankip Dan has gone out of his way to help OPs rewrite their questions if he is asked for guidance.

Comment: @blankip Copied from your question: `What do I look at next?` If that's not asking for troubleshooting, then what is? The other mods obviously also thought so as well. Looking forward to hearing more about your previous moderator experience. If you make inaccurate accusations and claim "BS", then you should probably expect an accuracy check.

Answer (score 0):

Blankip, I agree with you. AFAICT, the moderators here have a very precise (but not well-explained) vision of what questions they want to see, and they are willing to expend a lot of effort keeping it that way. If you have a webmaster question outside of those parameters (and there are many), you should move to a different SE. In your particular case, SuperUser is a good bet for solving error messages.

In [this meta similar to yours](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/905/closed-question), a question about local SO is simultaneously disparaged as too general (and therefore duplicate of existing SO questions) AND as too specific (and therefore insufficiently useful to other readers). The Catch 22 is strong in this SE.